# Correlating multiple columns in a matrix to a single column in the same matrix

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have a matrix of 48 variables with 40 observation each. I am trying to correlate the first 47 columns separately to the 48th column. what I've tried to do is use cor command:

```
cor(x[,1:47], x[,48], method="kendall").
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Error in cor.test.default(Hj1[, 1:47], Hj1[48], method = "kendall") : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

Since each column is the same length, I understand it's not about the column lengths, but something else. what can it be?

Thanks!
David.

Comment: Make a reproducible example. It will help you understand your problem better anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your error message:

```
Error in cor.test.default(Hj1[, 1:47], Hj1[48], method = "kendall") : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

`Hj1[48]`.

That was a typo. You wanted `Hj1[,48]`

Comment: I did...> KendallHj1 <- cor.test(Hj1[,1:47], Hj1[,48], method="kendall")
Error in cor.test.default(Hj1[, 1:47], Hj1[, 48], method = "kendall") : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length

Comment: @DavidM make a reproducible example

Comment: Hi. just to make sure it's not a problem with my data, I've use the mtcars dataset in Rstudio. I tried to use the same code, with the same results. > Kendallmtcars <- cor.test(mtcars[ ,1:3], mtcars[ ,4], method="kendall")
Error in cor.test.default(mtcars[, 1:3], mtcars[, 4], method = "kendall") : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length                                                       I'm guessing it's because it doesn't sample columns one by one?

Comment: @DavidM In your original question you ran `cor(...)`. Now you're running `cor.test`. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've separated the column from the matrix and run the correlation successfully. 
In my original code it looks like this:

```
Hj1tox <- Hj1[,48]

Hj1_ab <- Hj1[,1:47]

cor(Hj1_ab, Hj1tox)
```